# Between of two strings

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, string

I have simple method in C# :

```
public static string BetweenOf(string ActualStr, string StrFirst, string StrLast)
        {
            return ActualStr.Substring(ActualStr.IndexOf(StrFirst) + StrFirst.Length, (ActualStr.Substring(ActualStr.IndexOf(StrFirst))).IndexOf(StrLast) + StrLast.Length);
        }
```

How can i optimise this ?

Comment: I suppose careful code profiling tells you that this method is actually the bottleneck in your application's performance?

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190533/how-to-find-substring-from-string-without-using-indexof-method-in-c

Comment: This method is tremendously slow if i call it 100,000 times so suggest an alternative logic for getting same Output as expressed in this function.

Comment: @Rahul: Why are you calling the method 100,000 times? I'm not talking about benchmarking the method independently; I'm talking about profiling your actual *application* code.

Comment: Oh, right, it's that "I think this is slow so I'm going to run it an egregious number of times and benchmark that to prove it!" mentality again.

Comment: it is a part of some process.see i have written my code if u can write better it would be of great help & commenting unecessarilly wont be of any use

Comment: Neither will optimizing unnecessarily. Pick your poison I suppose.

Comment: @Haim : Is no way related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190533/how-to-find-substring-from-string-without-using-indexof-method-in-c

Comment: ok , sorry i think you search substring solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how the code from [@Chris here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912155/between-of-two-strings/4912249#4912249) stacks up against a regular expression test:

```
void Main()
{
    string input = "abcdefghijklmnopq";
    string first = "de";
    string last = "op";
    Regex re1 = new Regex("de(.*)op", RegexOptions.None);
    Regex re2 = new Regex("de(.*)op", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    // pass 1 is JIT preheat
    for (int pass = 1; pass <= 2; pass++)
    {
        int iterations = 1000000;
        if (pass == 1)
            iterations = 1;

        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int index = 0; index < iterations; index++)
            BetweenOfFixed(input, first, last);
        sw.Stop();
        if (pass == 2)
            Debug.WriteLine("IndexOf: " + 
                sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");

        sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int index = 0; index < iterations; index++)
            BetweenOfRegexAdhoc(input, first, last);
        sw.Stop();
        if (pass == 2)
            Debug.WriteLine("Regex adhoc: " + 
                sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");

        sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int index = 0; index < iterations; index++)
            BetweenOfRegexCached(input, first, last);
        sw.Stop();
        if (pass == 2)
            Debug.WriteLine("Regex uncompiled: " +
                sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");

        sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int index = 0; index < iterations; index++)
            BetweenOfRegexCompiled(input, first, last);
        sw.Stop();
        if (pass == 2)
            Debug.WriteLine("Regex compiled: " +
                sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");
    }
}

public static string BetweenOfFixed(string ActualStr, string StrFirst,
    string StrLast)
{
    int startIndex = ActualStr.IndexOf(StrFirst) + StrFirst.Length;
    int endIndex = ActualStr.IndexOf(StrLast, startIndex);
    return ActualStr.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
}

public static string BetweenOfRegexAdhoc(string ActualStr, string StrFirst,
    string StrLast)
{
    // I'm assuming you don't replace the delimiters on every call
    Regex re = new Regex("de(.*)op", RegexOptions.None);
    return re.Match(ActualStr).Groups[1].Value;
}

private static Regex _BetweenOfRegexCached =
    new Regex("de(.*)op", RegexOptions.None);
public static string BetweenOfRegexCached(string ActualStr, string StrFirst,
    string StrLast)
{
    return _BetweenOfRegexCached.Match(ActualStr).Groups[1].Value;
}

private static Regex _BetweenOfRegexCompiled =
    new Regex("de(.*)op", RegexOptions.Compiled);
public static string BetweenOfRegexCompiled(string ActualStr, string StrFirst,
    string StrLast)
{
    return _BetweenOfRegexCompiled.Match(ActualStr).Groups[1].Value;
}
```

Output:

```
IndexOf: 1419ms
Regex adhoc: 7788ms
Regex uncompiled: 1074ms
Regex compiled: 682ms
```

Comment: did you run build this as release code, based on the `Debug.WriteLine` statements I guess you might have run this in the IDE as a debug build. I took your code and changed to `Console.WriteLine` and did a release build. Running from a console window I got the following results 399ms, 9083ms, 1258ms, 806ms. I tested on Framework 4.0.

Answer (score 4):

If I have understood what you want to do, I think your implementation is possibly not correct.

Here is an implementation that I believe will perform better at least in terms of the GC because it does not use multiple calls to `SubString` which create new strings on the heap which are only used temporarily.

```
public static string BetweenOfFixed(string ActualStr, string StrFirst, string StrLast)
{
  int startIndex = ActualStr.IndexOf(StrFirst) + StrFirst.Length;
  int endIndex = ActualStr.IndexOf(StrLast, startIndex);
  return ActualStr.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
}
```

It would be interesting to compare the performance of this vs. the regex solution.

Comment: Thanks!! But can you tell me why to declare startIndex,endIndex if they are of no use

Comment: Both are used, endIndex once and startIndex twice.

Comment: @Rahul, as @Simon has said, both are used. In the final SubString I used the StartIndex as the offset into the string and then use endIndex - startIndex to get the count of characters to extract from the string, this gives the portion of the string between strFirst and strLast.

Comment: I compared the code with regex, I'll post it as an answer with CW as I don't have anything to add to yours. Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912155/between-of-two-strings/5142350#5142350

Answer (score 2):

You could construct a regex:

```
var regex = strFirst + "(.*)" + strLast;
```

Your between text will be the first (and only) capture for the match.

Comment: You'll definitely want to use `Regex.Escape` on those strings.

Comment: @Kobi : Can you also tell me how to remove escape sequence because i do it by Replace("\n","").Replace("\0","").Replace("\\","") and so on.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a regular expression? This would probably be faster than building of temporary strings.
Also this would enable to easily and gently handle the case where no such string can be found.