# C# Extension Method Overload

Tags: c#, extension-methods, overloading

I have two extension methods:

```
    public static string ToString(this List<object> list, char delimiter)
    {
        return ToString<object>(list, delimiter.ToString());
    }

    public static string ToString(this List<object> list, string delimiter)
    {
        return ToString<object>(list, delimiter);
    }
```

When I use this:

```
    char delimiter = ' ';
    return tokens.ToString(delimiter);
```

It won't work.  The char overload doesn't show up in the code completion list either.  Can anybody tell me how to make this work?

**EDIT**

I accidentally forgot to mention that there are in fact 3 extension methods, the third being:

```
    public static string ToString<T>(this List<T> list, string delimiter)
    {
        if (list.Count > 0)
        {
            string s = list[0].ToString();

            for (int i = 1; i < list.Count; i++)
                s += delimiter + list[i].ToString();

            return s;
        }

        return "";
    }
```

Comment: Is it just me or your ToString method calls itself indefinitely?

Comment: Which is the type of the tokens variable?

Comment: See edit for my answer, as followup on your edit.

Comment: the last ToString should really use a StringBuilder instead of appending the list items to a local string...

Comment: @MikeCorcoran It should actually use `string.Join`... Which apparently is just as fast as StringBuilder, given you already have all the substrings in an IEnumerable of some sort.

Comment: @Mike I was unaware of the uses of StringBuilder until now.  Thanks for that!

Comment: There are a ton of reasons to love the MoreLinq project - ToDelimitedString is one of them. :)  http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/wiki/OperatorsOverview

Comment: @YoryeNathan Actually, I just tested the string.Join approach vs a loop appending to a StringBuilder using the Stopwatch test loop method shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5142350/1296733 and got ~270 for StringBuilder method and ~7680 for string.Join method.  string.Join is definitely simpler to implement though :D

Comment: @Thick_propheT How long was the array you were appending?

Comment: @Thick_propheT My test shows opposite results: http://pastebin.com/jWx3MGs6
String Builder: 00:00:00.7834645
String.Join: 00:00:00.2856708

Comment: You're right. Right after I posted that, I realized that I had a fatal flaw. Oops :[

Comment: @Thick_propheT string.Join sometimes actually uses String Builder, in cases that it isn't optimized for, but then it wouldn't harm performance. In general, it can only be equal to or better than String Builder, and therefore better be used when possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add reference to the class in which you have the extension methods:

```
using MyApplicationNamespace.ToStringExtensionClass;
```

VS / ReSharper doesn't offer to add reference automatically simply because the method is already recognized, just not with that particular signature.

Also, your methods themselves don't compile unless you have a third extension methods with generic parameter.

The way they work for me (compile and logically):

```
public static string ToString(this List<object> list, char delimiter)
{
    return ToString(list, delimiter.ToString());
}

public static string ToString(this List<object> list, string delimiter)
{
    return string.Join(delimiter, list);
}
```

Usage will then be:

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var str = list.Cast<object>().ToList().ToString(' ');
```

If you want to avoid casting and make the methods generic, change them to:

```
public static string ToString<T>(this List<T> list, char delimiter)
{
    return ToString(list, delimiter.ToString());
}

public static string ToString<T>(this List<T> list, string delimiter)
{
    return string.Join(delimiter, list);
}
```

And then the usage is much cleaner:

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var str = list.ToString(' ');
```

**EDIT**

So after your edit I understand your problem better.
You should lose the non-generic methods and have generic overload to accept char as well.

```
public static string ToString<T>(this List<T> list, char delimiter)
{
    return ToString(list, delimiter.ToString());
}

public static string ToString<T>(this List<T> list, string delimiter)
{
    ...
}
```

Also, the logic you are trying to implement can be easily achieved with:

```
string.Join(delimiter, list);
```

So you can basically delete all of those methods and just use that, unless you really want it as an extension method for lists.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to do what you're describing.  I guess I'm somewhat of a newb.  I tried:

    return ListExtensions.ToString(tokens, delimiter);

and it will display the char overload, but it doesn't like tokens for some reason...

Comment: @Thick_propheT That is probably because you didn't make the methods generic, meaning it expects `List<object>` - which tokens isn't. Try using the two generic methods at the end of the answer.

Comment: You're right, I tried: return ListExtension.ToString(new List<object>(), delimiter); and it was 110% satisfied XD

Comment: @Thick_propheT That would create a new and empty list... Are you sure that's the code you've used?

Comment: Oh, no, it's definitely not what I need, I was just trying to see what it would take to satisfy visual studio.

Comment: @Thick_propheT Oh I see, well great :). I bet the compiler told you it couldn't find an overload which fits the parameters. That should give you the hint that something is wrong with that - always read the errors carefully.

Comment: >unless you really want it as an extension method for lists.

Yes, I'm trying to get this to work for lists.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you are specifying the type of object for your generic List and not making it a generic method.

See if it works when you define something like the following:

```
public static string ToString<T>(this List<T> list, char delimiter) 
{ 
    return ToString<T>(list, delimiter.ToString()); 
} 

public static string ToString<T>(this List<T> list, string delimiter) 
{ 
    return String.join(list, delimiter); 
}
```

Your original function with the string delimiter was just calling itself so you'll have to change your `ToString<T>(this List<T> list, string delimiter)` to do something useful here like a String.join

Comment: This will result with endless and useless recursion.

Comment: Haha yes, I see that now. I don't actually know what original poster was trying for in the string extension method. I guess there's a reason they call this stackoverflow

Comment: The fact he wants a string and uses a list and delimiter kind of narrows down the options.