# Finding a byte array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, indexing

I was wondering what would be the best approach towards finding the index of a sub-array  from within another byte array in C#. For example if I have the following as my main array.

```
byte[] inputArray = {0xFF,0xDD,0xA,0xF,0x1,0x2,0x78,0x05,0x00,0x01};
byte[] tobeFound = {0x78,0x05};
```

Now I want to find the byte array "tobeFound" inside inputArray. And I should get the index 6. This is a short example. Both arrays can be very large.

So what should I go for? LINQ, Array.IndexOf ?? I need to have good performance as well.

Thanks for any pointers and sharing some experience!

Comment: why don't you write a little console app that does performance testing on your various solutions and see which one performs the best

Comment: you could do pretty much the same as this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190533/how-to-find-substring-from-string-without-using-indexof-method-in-c/4190590#4190590

Comment: @Mark, i use bytes, not strings

Comment: @Jason, if someone has done it, may be can guide me with some info about speed before I write the code. That is why I requested to share some experience.

Comment: @Wajih: Dude..a string is an array of chars. Replace string with byte[] in the example I gave you, and it'll work. I thought you'd piece that together.

Comment: @Wajih: If you're concerned about efficiency, look at codekaizen's answer though. That'll definitely be more efficient, although now I'm concerned you'll have trouble implementing it.

Comment: @Mark, I will look at it. Seems that may have to change the implementation to pure byte arrays. Nevertheless, I will give it a try.

Comment: Your sample seems flawed, the toBeFound array does not appear (as array) in the target.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the well-tested [Boyer-Moore string search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm), since you are essentially searching a string (the bytes can be considered characters).

Here is what appears to be [a decent implementation of Boyer-Moore in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/BoyerMooreSearch.aspx) for strings (along with turbo Boyer-Moore and another I'd never heard of). Converting these to use `Byte[]` should be trivial.

Comment: well I am not searching strings actually,I am limited to bytes.

Comment: The essence is the same: a string is just a sequence of bytes. The algorithm will work equally well for a byte array.

Comment: @codekaizen: That's a cool algorithm! Never would have thought of that.