# Finding the indexOf a string without using indexOf method

Tags: java, string

Working on a little java program currently, my task is to understand more on how the indexOf method works without actually using the indexOf method. I feel I am close having the code correct. I'll provide my code and my test file. I want to only use the charAt(), length(), and equals() methods for my program.

```
public class MiniString
{
   private String str;


   public MiniString(String x)
   {
      this.str = x;
   }


   public int findIndexOf(int a)
   {
      int counter = 0;
      for(int i = 0; i < this.str.length(); i++)
      {
         counter++;
      } 

      char[] arr = new char[counter];

      for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
      {
         arr[i] = this.str.charAt(i);
      }
   }
}
```

Here is what I am passing into my method

```
public class TestMiniString
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      MiniString s1 = new MiniString("Hello world, welcome to the Java world.");



      System.out.println(s1.findIndexOf('w'));
      System.out.println(s1.findIndexOf('m'));
      System.out.println(s1.findIndexOf('x'));
      System.out.println(s1.findIndexOf('J'));
      System.out.println(s1.findIndexOf('a'));
      System.out.println();

}
```

Comment: there is now question/problem. we don't support "my code is not working" posts. this also sounds like homework.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4190533/982161

Comment: small hint: you need at least a `return` in findIndexOf

Comment: I should reword, how would you find the index of a string without actually using indexOf method

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) if (str.charAt(i) == a) return i; return -1;`

Comment: *I feel I am close having the code correct.* Not really. Your code just copies the characters to an array. How is that supposed to help?

Answer (score 1):

It is quite simple. `String` in `Java` is a array of the chars internally. Using `charAt(int index)` you have direct access to this. All you have to is just loop this array and find first occurrence of the required character:

```
public final class MiniString {
    private final String str;

    public MiniString(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

    public int indexOf(int ch) {
        for (int pos = 0; pos < str.length(); pos++)
            if (str.charAt(pos) == ch)
                return pos;

        return -1;
    }

    public int indexOf(String str) {
        if (str == null || str.trim().isEmpty())
            return -1;

        for (int pos = 0; pos < this.str.length() - str.length(); pos++) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= str.length(); i++) {
                if (i == str.length())
                    return pos;
                if (this.str.charAt(pos + i) != str.charAt(i))
                    break;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
}
```

But be ware of exotic symbols, that is codded with more than one character (e.g. 
Chinese characters). So this is not universal solution for all situations.

Look at [Java charAt used with characters that have two code units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150530/java-charat-used-with-characters-that-have-two-code-units)
 for more details.

`indexOf(String str)` implementation is strigtforward. Thare're many special algorithms for [String searching algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm).

Comment: Oleg thanks for your answer, what if we wanted to find the index of with lets says a String passed in as a parameter instead of an int, I am referring to the other method of indexOf.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. Hopefully, you like it.

```
    static int indexOf(String string, String substring ) {

    String crt = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {

        if (string.charAt(i) == ' ')
            crt = "";
        else
            crt += string.charAt(i);
        if (crt.equalsIgnoreCase(substring))
            return i - crt.length() + 1;
    }
    return -1; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int subStringIndex(String str, String substr) {
        int strlen = str.length();
        int substrlen = substr.length();
       int count=0;
       int substrlen2=substr.length();
        if (substrlen >= 1) {
            for(int i=0;i<strlen-substrlen+1;i++){
                String A=str.substring(i,substrlen2);
                if(A.equalsIgnoreCase(substr)){
                return count+1;
                }else{
                    count++;
                    substrlen2++;
                }
            }
            return -1;              
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: Please explain how your program works and properly format your code.

Answer (score 0):

Find the word index from main string also find which is main string and which is sub string

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
   
    String string2="Today is a great day";
    String string1="great day";
    int a=string1.length();
    int b=string2.length();
    String [] p=string1.split(" ");
    String [] q=string2.split(" ");
    if(a>b)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<q.length;i++)
        {
            String x=q[i];         
            char d=x.charAt(0);
            for(int k=0;k<string1.length();k++)
            {
                if(string1.charAt(k)==d)
                {
                     if(string1.charAt(k-1)== ' ')
                 System.out.println(k);                     
                }               
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {         
        for(int j=0;j<p.length;j++)
        {
            String x=p[j];
            char d=x.charAt(0);
            for(int n=0;n<string2.length();n++)
            {
                if(string2.charAt(n)==d)
                {
                    if(string2.charAt(n-1)== ' ')
                System.out.println(n);
                }
            }
        }
    }    
}
```